# Is the AF Nikkor 35mm f/2D lens compatible with my Nikon D5200?

Tags: nikon, aperture-priority, nikon-d5200, shutter-priority

Can I use a Nikkor AF 35mm f/2D lens with my Nikon D5200 camera in aperture- or shutter-priority modes? Will the camera automatically adjust the exposure by changing the shutter/aperture in A/S modes?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

See this link for an answer to almost every lens compatibility question: http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm#dslr

So YES, your lens will automatically adjust exposure in PSAM modes (this is called light metering). Hope this helps.